# magento show product collection by id

Tags: product, product-list, product-collection, custom-collection

I want to show some *specific product on product listing page* :

like `product_collection.phtml`

there is a code that grab the collection

```
  $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

It show all products in particular category but I want to show few product by there ids may be array of product ids like

```
$productids=array(11,22,1,4);
```

how can I do that add filter or any other way ?..

i tried below code but it is not working .
code of product_collection.phtml:

```
        <?php
/* added code for filter start */
        $productIds = array(1,3,2);
        $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

/* added code for filter ends */
/*order code
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

*/
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

    ?>
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = !empty($cols)?$cols:$this->getColumnCount(); ?>  
    <div class="category-products">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>



        <div class="products-block" id="products-grid">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <div class="row products-grid">
            <?php endif ?>

                    <?php echo $_product->getName().'<br>';?>

                <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('div.products-row'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
            </div>
        <div class="toolbar-bottom">
            <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `getLoadedProductCollection()` method, you can create your own custom collection. It should somewhat looks like this.

```
//use product ids that you need to show in this array
$productIds = array(11, 12, 1, 4);

//loads collection based on Ids
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

//loop through custom collection in order to grab data
foreach ($collection as $item) {
     $item->getName();
}
```

Comment: giving downvote is ok. May I know what is the reason ?

Comment: Same answer just look and fill diff this is not a good way to keep both answer same

Comment: I have not down vote your answer.

Comment: @KeyulShah:that +1 from my side for put a good answer

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try the Below code.

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

Or Try One of them.

```
$products =$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$products ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));


$products->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(entity_id,'".implode(',',$productIds)."')"

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->getEntityId();
        echo $product->getSku();
    }
```

In collection you have to add filter using `addAttributeToFilter` and pass the `$productIds` `array.`

Comment: please update the error

Comment: what is actual error so we can help

Comment: i wrote below code
 $productIds = array(1,3,2);
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
it shows all products not filtered result

Comment: does product id same as entity id?

Comment: yeah , in need to filter via product ids, see my updated quesion